# Laravel form model binding, related table value

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

The thing is about an input field and retrieving related data using `Form::model()` binding. How can I do that? Binding results are empty on text input `qty`. I'm thinking into do the hack thing from model... is possible from `model()`?

### Form (app/views/products/edit.blade.php)

```
{{ Form::model($product, array(
  'method' => 'PATCH', 
  'route' => array('products.update', $product->id),
  'class' => 'form-inline'
)) }}
{{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
{{ Form::text('name') }}
{{ Form::label('qty', 'Price:') }}
{{ Form::text('qty') }} <!-- here's da thing! -->
{{ Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

### app/controllers/ProductsController.php

```
class ProductsController extends BaseController {
  public function edit($id) {
    $product = Product::find($id);
    if (is_null($product)) return Redirect::route('products.index');
    return View::make('products.edit', compact('product'));
  }
}
```

### app/models/

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $fillable = array('name');

  public function prices() {
    return $this->hasMany('Price');
  }
  public function images() {
    return $this->morphMany('Image', 'imageable');
  }
}
class Price extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = 'product_prices';
  public $timestamps = true;
  protected $fillable = array('qty');

  public static $rules = array(
    'qty' => 'required|numeric'
  );

  public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Product');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your `$product` has data on it?

```
Route::get('/test', function() {

    $user = new User;
    $user->email = 'me@mydomain.com';
    return View::make('test', compact('user'));

});
```

View (test.blade.php):

```
{{ Form::model($user, array(
  'method' => 'PATCH', 
)) }}
{{ Form::label('email', 'E-mail:') }}
{{ Form::text('email') }} <!-- here's da thing! -->
{{ Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay; thinking about an API idea. Taking course about and convinces, will try yours

Answer (score 0):

Laravel form model binding, related table value:

```
Route::patch('dashboard/product/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'Dashboard\Product\ProductController@update',
    'as' => 'dashboard.products.update'
]);
```

in display form edit:

```
{{ Form::model($product, array(
                      'method' => 'PATCH', 
                      'route' => array('dashboard.products.update', $product->id),
                    )) }}
    //enter code here
{{ Form::close() }}
```